# cannot convert from ‘string’ to ‘Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am using the below code,

```
WorkspaceInfo workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo("$/UKNML1234_1");
Uri serverUri = workspaceInfo.ServerUri;
TfsTeamProjectCollection server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(serverUri);
var versionControlServer = server.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
Workspace WS = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(versionControlServer.AuthorizedUser);
```

but I am getting the error

```
cannot convert from ‘string’ to ‘Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Edit: the error is generated on the fifth line at `versionControlServer.AuthorizedUser`

Comment: What line does that error message refer to?

Comment: Its from the versionControlServer.AuthorizedUser on the fifth line, I will edit the question to include this info.

Comment: Hm, well ok. The [`AuthorizedUser` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff733857(v=vs.120)) is of type `string` while [`GetWorkspace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff732927(v=vs.120)) expects a `TfsTeamProjectCollection`. Which means your usage is incorrect. What did you intend to do?

Comment: ^^ I am _guessing_ it should be `Workspace WS = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);` ?

Comment: That seems to have cleared the error, I had tried that before but when I asked AI if that was how toi fix it it said it was not. I will get the rest of the code working then if it does fix it add it as the answer.

Comment: _"when I asked AI"_ - do not trust AI. You _may_ get the one or other odd idea but be aware that ChatGPT _does not know how to code_. Treat its answers as coming from someone you absolutely despise and who stabbed you in the back before. They might tell you something good, but you _never_ know.

Comment: @ProgramMasher Prime example of how AI can hallucinate. As knowledge workers we must think for ourselves and not depend on AI tools that many claim will "replace" us